# Dataframe add new value for certain value, make it faster

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to check if a certain column has a certain value in a row. If so, a new column should be created with a value.

I have solved this problem too. Unfortunately my code is very slow. Does anyone have an idea how I could solve this to make it go faster? There must be a more elegant solution.

```
temp = []
for index, row in df_event.iterrows():
  if row['event'] == ("view"):
    temp.append(1)
  if row['event'] == ("addtocart"):
    temp.append(2)
  if row['event'] == ("transaction"):
    temp.append(3)

df['event'] = temp
df['event'].head()
```

This is my dataframe and what I want

[image]

Each event should get a code. View =1, addtocart = 2, transaction = 3

How could I replace my code with a `map` function?

Comment: Create dictionary and use `map`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also looked at this link and did some research. I do not quite understand how I could apply this to my problem. Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: Use `df['code'] = df['event'].map({"view":1, "addtocart":2, "addtocart":3})`

Comment: Thank you very much! And I wish you all the best and a big thank you for your time and effort. Thank you!

Comment: You edited the question after it was closed, but I see your problem is already solved. Please only edit the questions that you wish to be reopened.